# Optimization of SQL

Tags: sql

I have a query regarding a sql query where i have 3 conditions on same column

```
AND TRP.X_ID <> '0' 

AND TRP.X_ID <> ' ' 

AND TRP.X_ID  IS not NULL;
```

can this be handled with 1 or 2 conditions within `where` clause.

Answer (score 6):

Well, if a column is currently NULL, it is never equal, not not equal, to any specific value, so you can skip the 3rd test immediately. As for the other two, you can condense it to:

```
TRP.X_ID not in ('0',' ')
```

which is shorter to read, but unlikely to change how the code performs - in e.g. SQL Server, it's internally re-written back into individual comparisons.

Comment: +1...but just curious: does your first sentence still stand, regardless of the settings of ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_DEFAULTS?

Comment: @davek - it's not a question I'd thought of - you're correct that if ANSI_NULLs is off (on SQL Server), then it's no longer correct. But if I find someone turning ANSI_NULLs off, I'm going to (*insert violence here*)

Answer (score 2):

```
and coalesce(trp.x_id, '') not in ('', '0')
```

**EDIT**

or (mysql version)

```
length(case trp.x_id when '0' then '' else trp.x_id end) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for comments but this query does not reduce the cost of quering the DB. i need to optimize the data

Comment: In fact, it's probably increasing the cost with the call to `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this... this is really just a syntactical optimization... sql optimizer will interpret these equally (as far as performance).

```
AND NULLIF(NULLIF(TRP.X_ID,'0'),' ') IS NOT NULL
```